# Is there a way to auto-resize programs like in Windows 7 and up?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, window-manager, utilities

One of my favorite Windows features is the ability to slam a program into the side of the screen to auto-resize it to fill that half of the screen.

Is there any program I can download for Mac that makes this feature available on macOS?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [BetterSnapTool](https://itunes.apple.com/US/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12) on the App Store:

> BetterSnapTool allows you to easily manage your window positions and
> sizes by either dragging them to one of the screen's corners or to the
> top, left or right side of the screen. This enables you to easily
> maximize your windows, position them side by side or even resize them
> to quarters of the screen.
>
> [image]

I had a client show this to me and they seemed pretty pleased with it.  It also has a rating of 5 stars with 3500+ reviews.  I personally don't use it (no need) but from the looks of it, it appears to be a good solution.